# 2 different consumer application instances with the same group id consuming messages from the same topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

What happens If there are 2 different consumer application instances with the same group id consume from the same topic ?

Example : If the consumer application is developed by 2 different teams, running parallel with the same group id and reading from the same kafka topic.

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka we have `Consumer` and `Consumer groups`.

Kafka builds on the publish-subscribe model with the advantages of a message queuing system. It achieves this with-

- the use of consumer groups
- message retention by brokers

Consumers that share the same `group id` are part of the same Consumer group. The Consumers from the same Consumer Group works as message queuing system, so if a message is being consumed by one of the consumers, it won't be available to be consumed by another consumer in the same group.

Consider the below picture-

[image]

Here we have two different Consumer groups, A and B, and as we can see the Consumers in the same group are not assigned the same Topic Partition.

The consumers in a group divides the topic partitions as fairly amongst themselves as possible by establishing that **each partition is only consumed by a single consumer from the group**.

Comment: what happens in the use case i have mentioned in the question ?

Comment: First thing is Consumers get attached to the Partition, Topic is just a logical grouping of Partitions. Consider these scenarios in your case, 1- When Topic is only having one partition- Only one of the 2 Consumer application would be able to consume the data, 2nd would be idle. 2- Topic has 2 Partitions - Both the consumers will be attached to 1 partition each. 3- Topic has more number of partitions - As mentioned in the answer, consumers will divide the partitions fairly amongst themselves. Bottom line is 1 Partition gets attached to only one Consumer.